# How to use rapidonvif library in VS Code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gsoap, onvif

How do I use [rapidonvif](https://github.com/linkingvision/rapidonvif) library in **VS Code** and write simple ONVIF tasks like camera discovery and video streaming in C++?

I didn't find any tutorial.

Comment: It looks like this library only supports Visual Studio (Community, Enterprise, Pro) directly. Anything else you will have some work to build and install because there is no CMake or Makefile in the code.

Comment: @drescherjm And how to build it in Visual Studio? Is there any other ONVIF library that can be simply used in VS Code or in any other light IDE like Qt or CodeBlock?

Comment: There are project files for Visual Studio Community. [https://github.com/linkingvision/rapidonvif/tree/master/win32](https://github.com/linkingvision/rapidonvif/tree/master/win32) and an example here: [https://github.com/linkingvision/rapidonvif/tree/master/example/client/onvifclientwin32](https://github.com/linkingvision/rapidonvif/tree/master/example/client/onvifclientwin32)